# Tricky f4m extraction (video scraping)

Tags: video, web-scraping, video-streaming

I want to scrape video from the page.
The page with video: http://www.afl.com.au/video/2015-10-28/forward-of-the-future-v-forward-of-the-past

The key for achieving this is the link to the manifest file in the network logs.
http://bpmultihlsvod5257.ngcdn.telstra.com/hds/amlst:eyJkIjowLCJwIjoiaW5nZXN0X2FmbGZpbG1zX3ZvZC84MDA2ODYvVk9EX1NvdXJjZS8yMDE1LTEwLTI4XzEwLTMyLTM0LTk1NzAiLCJUYWciOiJoZHMiLCJ0IjoiZmxhc2giLCJ2cCI6W3siYiI6IjI0MDAiLCJoIjo3MjAsInciOjEyODB9LHsiYiI6IjE4MDAiLCJoIjo0MDYsInciOjcyMH0seyJiIjoiMTEwMCIsImgiOjQwNiwidyI6NzIwfSx7ImIiOiI3MDAiLCJoIjozNjAsInciOjY0MH0seyJiIjoiNDAwIiwiaCI6MjcwLCJ3Ijo0ODB9LHsiYiI6IjIzNiIsImgiOjE4MCwidyI6MjMwfSx7ImIiOiIxNjgiLCJoIjoxODAsInciOjMyMH1dfQ==/manifest.f4m?SIGV=2&IS=0&ET=1463393555&CIP=116.103.252.126&KO=1&KN=7&US=ffeac87aac42c148e0874ea0910cb11bd022c375

Using this link you can easily stream the video, e.g. with youtube-dl.
This is what I need.

The problem is I cannot find out how to compose this URL programmatically.
 None of the ids could be found in network logs (at least with Firebug, which is itself buggy by the way). Could anyone give some clues? (PS sometimes there is the direct mp4 link in the logs but not always)